# Глобальная переменная в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, переменные

Пишу JS для своего сайта, в этом деле начинающий, есть такая ситуация:

Есть событие, например "**А**", после которого становятся доступны другие события например "**А-1**"...
При наступлении события **А** запускается функция, в ходе которой создается переменная **data**. При наступлении события **А-1** и др., запускается функция которой нужно обработать переменную **data** которая была создана рание.

Моих знаний хватило только на то, чтоб сделать переменную глобальной, типа так:

```
let data;
$('#A').on('click', function (){... data = 'myData' ...});
$('#A-1').on('click', function (){... if(data){...} ...});
$('#A-2').on('click', function (){... if(data){...} ...});
...
```

Читал что создавать такие глобальные переменные - плохая практика, как решение - нашел что можно взять кусок кода в фигурные душки "{}", и теперь эта переменная глобальна только для этого блока:

```
{
let data;
$('#A').on('click', function (){... data = 'myData' ...});
$('#A-1').on('click', function (){... if(data){...} ...});
$('#A-2').on('click', function (){... if(data){...} ...});
...
}
```

Код работает как надо пока что, но правильное ли это решение? Какие есть другие решения?

Comment: Нет конечно, это плохая практика. Но многие ею пользуются

Comment: @AzizUmarov а как тогда лучше?

Comment: Пользоваться параметрами функции не вариант?

Comment: Смотря что это за данные. Иногда их можно запихнуть в data атрибуты в html.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko была у меня такая мысль, но данных много, не хотелось бы засорять html

Comment: В таком случае пишите класс, у класса будут свойства, поля (для данных), методы(для событий, вычислений, условий).